# Angular2 ngModel changes multiple values because it is in a ngFor

Tags: typescript, angular, ngfor

I have a set of conditions each of them have different templates, i all ready fixed the dynamic content loader. But now i have an issue when i select a condition it affects every row because it is in a ngFor..

Here you can see the result for a better look:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e4xg3q4ym2zdhw8/condition.jpg?dl=0

As you can see the template is different for each row but if i select a condition on a row it all changes. Do you know how to work around this for loop or is there a other way to fix this?

Here is the code of the template:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" *ngFor="#condition of conditions;#conditionindex = index">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" [ngModel]="selectedCondition" (ngModelChange)="onChange(conditionindex, selectedCondition=$event)">
            <option *ngFor="#c of catalog;#catalogindex = index" [value]="catalogindex">{{c.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <condition-detail [condition]="condition"></condition-detail>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="newCondition()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
```

This is the code of the component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'condition-builder',
templateUrl: 'app/conditionbuilder.component.html',
directives: [ConditionDetailComponent]
})

export class ConditionBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
    selectedCondition: any = 'DateCondition';
    conditions: Condition[] = [];
    catalog: Condition[] = [];

constructor(private _conditionService: ConditionService) { }

getConditions() {
    this._conditionService.getConditions().then(conditions => this.catalog = conditions);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getConditions();
}

onChange(conditionsIndex, catalogIndex) {
    console.log(this.catalog[catalogIndex]);
    console.log(this.selectedCondition);
    this.conditions[conditionsIndex] = this.catalog[catalogIndex];
}

newCondition() {
    this.conditions.push(this.catalog[0]);
    console.log(this.selectedCondition);
}

deleteCondition():void {
    this.conditions.pop();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you expect. You bind every select to the same `selectedCondition`

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="selectedCondition[conditionIndex]" (ngModelChange)="onChange(conditionindex, selectedCondition[conditionIndex]=$event)">
```

You need to ensure `selectedCondition` is initialized to an array of the same length as `conditions`

Comment: I am expecting that every single row is acting on his own. So if i select the second condition row to be the SelectCondition that the select option show SelectCondition and also the template of SelectCondition. That last part is all ready fixed.. If i add your code to my template it will change the template but will not show the option of the selected condition.